# Can I make a CD or DVD to install Microsoft updates?

Tags: windows-update

Say I'm setting up (brand new) multilple PCs at one time and I don't have enough ethernet ports to hook them all up to the internet at once, **is it possible to create a CD/DVD of updates that I could use instead?** I know you can download update packages and run them as a stand-alone installer... but I would want to deploy them all at once from the CD/DVD without any further user interaction after inserting the disc. Maybe kick off some batch/script to do the deployment.

Comment: Are these machines a part of a windows AD domain?  or just a bunch of independent PCs...  can you give us a little more insight to your network/setup?  Knowing this will narrow down the best method for you.

Comment: In this instance they are Windows 7 machines on a Windows AD network server 2008.

Comment: are all the machines hooked up to the internal network?

Comment: @Keltari Right now, no they are not. When I actually deploy the machine to the correct location then they will be. I'm just doing the basic setup at my location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the WSUS Offline Update project. I'm sure it's not Microsoft approved but I'm not aware that it's considered illegal either.

http://download.wsusoffline.net/

While I think it's possible to make a DVD by copying the Client directory, I think it's probably better to use an External USB drive or else a Flash Drive. It's unclear to me if the updater process needs write access to the directory it runs from. I've used this but have only ever used it on a large Flash Drive or External USB Drive.

Comment: This utility also let you create an ISO with the downloaded packages.

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to slipstream whatever you want into a Windows install disc.  Basically, you apply the updates to the install media, then install the OS on the computer, and it has the updates you wanted.  This worked for Windows XP, but I think Vista, 7 and 8 use a different method.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/slipstream-windows-7-sp1/3d46ab8f-d46c-484d-84f4-fe8446311c34

Comment: Ive never been a fan of slipstreaming.  The reason is once you slipstream updates into a disc, Wndows wants you to use that disc from that point on as it would complain the original install disc was the wrong version.  It isnt as big a deal lately... just my humble opinion.

Comment: Yup. We always just slipstreamed the main service packs and then kept those around.

Answer (score 0):

Since these machines are part of a domain and *will* be hooked up to the internal network, you should take a look at Microsofts Windows Server Update Services ([WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx)).  WSUS is a free application that allows you to manage and deploy MS updates to your domain.  It isnt as versatile as some of their paid products, but it is actually still extremely powerful.  It will allow you to download MS updates to the server, so your machines get patches locally and not from the internet.  Also, it allows you to approve/reject updates as you wish and deploy them to individual/groups of machines/entire domain.  It gives you complete control over the MS update process.  Windows Update on the individual machines will now point to the WSUS server and not the internet.  Also, you can take away the users ability to install/ignore updates.  You make all the decisions.

I know this isnt exactly what you asked for, but I believe its a better solution overall.

Comment: I don't know enough to correct this, but can you clarify? `Windows Update on the individual machines will not point to the WSUS server and not the internet.`

Comment: good catch.  Fixed it to "Now" instead of "not"