# Is there a script that can retrieve the current Windows 7 security updates?

Tags: windows-7, script, automation, windows-update

I need a way to download the windows 7 security updates for multiple computers that do not have Internet connections, so running the windows update is out. What I would like is a way that I can automate the download process to my admin site then push them out on DVD, possibly automate the install as well.

Comment: Does it have to be via DVD? Have you looked at [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx) yet?

Comment: Yeah, the systems are standalone systems, which make the update processes a bit tedious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline update of Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/7261/offline-update-of-windows), [Can I make a CD or DVD to install Microsoft updates?](http://superuser.com/questions/587093/can-i-make-a-cd-or-dvd-to-install-microsoft-updates) ...

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft have a [DVD ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39202) available to download each month containing the security updates for all systems.

Comment: Thank you! I take it that this is simply the monthly updates or is it cumulative?

Comment: @Tim I've never had to use it but I think it's only that month. It's only Windows; it doesn't include fixes for Office etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use **WSUS Offline** to get all required updates:

http://download.wsusoffline.net/

Select which language and Windows you need and the tool downloads all updates:

[image]