# How to use external drive for Windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-update

So, the situation I'm in might seem strange, but I certainly can't be the only one. I bought an awesome, inexpensive mini-tablet (a Winbook). It's running FULL Windows 8.1, but it only came with a 10GB internal SSD. Windows consumes almost all of that. I've got a 32 GB SD card inserted so I can load up pictures, movies, or whatever.

However, I'm unable to do Windows updates because it only has 300MB of space left on the main drive. I've cleaned out every program, file, and disk cleanup scan result I could. This thing is bare! But it's still not enough free space.

Does anyone know of a way to use an external disk for Windows updates or to extend the primary disk space using an external drive?

Comment: Related: [Can I make a CD or DVD to install Microsoft updates?](http://superuser.com/questions/587093/can-i-make-a-cd-or-dvd-to-install-microsoft-updates)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/)

[WSUS Offline Update](http://www.wsusoffline.net/) will allow you to download the updates to the directory of your choice.

[image]

You then hit **Start** to update your system.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The trouble you will have is with updates the un-installers and such are closely linked into the OS partition and can't be moved to another drive.  You might be able to get away with junctions but it is likely your SD card is not available to the OS at boot so unless you are lucky or careful you could end up with a non-working system.  Originally you state that it comes with a 10GB Internal SSD - usual sizes are 8GB or 16GB.

After you cleared out all the programs and files did you remember to empty the recycle bin? Also running disk clean up may reclaim some disk space.  You should also consider the hibernation file and the swap file to reduced in size.  You can move these do another drive, plenty of other questions at stackexchange on that topic.

If you have *full* Windows 8.1 then you can turn on compression - this should give you enough room for now for some updates.

Also there are apps out there like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) and [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) that you can use to analyse your disk and hunt down any files you may be able to remove.  I would be wary of removing any windows or system files.  If you get the portable versions of these apps and install them to USB or SD card then you won't have to install them to your tablet and they can be used on any PC for the future.  You can find out more about portable apps in general from [their site](http://portableapps.com/)

I removed some of your tags so your question is more specific.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not really answer the author's question.  The author has already done most of what you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

If you just bought your miniPC, then you might not have a lot of data on it. If you are comfortable with installing windows then this would make the process much simpler.

You can try to reinstall Windows 8.1 from a USB drive or a CD and use The ""Micro SD"" as the installation drive. Then the MicroSd will become your primary "Hard Drive" and the updates will be downloaded to it. This is a one time process which is a bit tricky if you are a newbie but it won't trouble you in the future and you don't have to rely on third party apps.

I would suggest you to buy a 64gig card as 32 will get filled up really easliy if you are string a lot of media content.

If you are ready to go ahead and install windows and make the MIcroSD the primary "Hard Drive" - Then this link might Help=== http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Windows-8-from-USB

I would suggest you to install Windows from USB as it is in my opinion easier and will be handy!

Hope I helped! :)